# Magento 2 Rest API Order edit

Tags: rest, magento2, guzzle

I'm trying to figure out how to edit an order after I requested it. 
I made a custom attribute whether an order is exported or not.

I first get all orders with status not exported and after I exported them, I want to change the custom attribute to exported.

What is the REST request to edit/update an order? I keep getting error messages like:

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":
{"fieldName":"entity"}
```

This is my code:

```
    $json = array(
        "entity_id" => $id, 
        "extension_attributes" => array(
            "custom_export_attribute" => "exported",
            )
        );
    $webapi = new ApiClient('https://dev.local.nl', self::$username, self::$password); 
    $response = $webapi->getClient()->request('PUT', '/rest/V1/orders/create', [

        'headers'   => [                
            'Authorization'             => "Bearer " . $webapi->getToken(),
            'Content-Type'              => "application/json"
        ],
        'body'     => json_encode($json)

    ]);    
    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

I also tried:

```
 $webapi->getClient()->request('PUT', '/rest/V1/orders/'.$id,
```

Answer (score 1):

To edit / update order details, the Magento 2 `/V1/orders` accepts `POST` request method. As per [Magento 2 Dev Doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1SavePost), it accepts the request body in below format (You can find whole JSON request in documentation page):

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {

        }
    }
}
```

So, you just need to update the `$json` variable as:

```
$json = [
    "entity"=> [
        "entity_id" => $id,
        "extension_attributes" => [
            "custom_export_attribute" => "exported"
        ]
    ]
]
```

And than invoke with `POST` request method instead of `PUT`. In my suggestion prefer to use [Create API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1SavePut) for new order creation.